# How can i add location icon in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, mkmapview

How can I add this things in my project. Are they integrated in `MKMapView`?

I didn't find anything in the internet about them.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: bye creating UIView on Map

Comment: okey, but how can i setup that system location icon whiteout using external images? (sorry for my english )

Comment: is there something like the "i" circle in the top right of the screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create two buttons on the top of the `MKMapView` add their constraints then write this code in `viewDidLayourSubviews` function to round the desired corners and add the shadows and images to the buttons. Choose their light grey background color from the identity inspector.

   ```
   override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

   let infoButtonShape = CAShapeLayer()
   infoButtonShape.bounds = infoButton.frame
   infoButtonShape.position = infoButton.center

   let locationButtonShape = CAShapeLayer()
   locationButtonShape.bounds = locationButton.frame
   locationButtonShape.position = locationButton.center


   infoButton.clipsToBounds = true
   infoButton.layer.masksToBounds = false
   infoButton.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
   infoButton.layer.shadowRadius = 2
   infoButton.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
   infoButton.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 2, height: -2)
   infoButton.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: infoButton.bounds).cgPath



   locationButton.clipsToBounds = true
   locationButton.layer.masksToBounds = false
   locationButton.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
   locationButton.layer.shadowRadius = 2
   locationButton.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
   locationButton.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -2, height: 2)
   locationButton.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: locationButton.bounds).cgPath

   infoButton.layer.shouldRasterize = true
   locationButton.layer.shouldRasterize = true

   locationButtonShape.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: locationButton.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [UIRectCorner.bottomLeft , UIRectCorner.bottomRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width:10.0, height:10.0)).cgPath

   infoButtonShape.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: infoButton.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [UIRectCorner.topRight , UIRectCorner.topLeft], cornerRadii: CGSize(width:10.0, height:10.0)).cgPath

   infoButton.layer.mask = infoButtonShape
   locationButton.layer.mask = locationButtonShape

   infoButton.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
   locationButton.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit


   infoButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "information-icon-3"), for: .normal)
   locationButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "LocationArrow-512"), for: .normal)


   }
   ```
2. Then add the `IBAction` of the button to update the location

   ```
    let manager = CLLocationManager()

   func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

   //Use location.last add to map then stop updating location
   manager.stopUpdatingLocation()

   }

   @IBAction func updateLocationAction(_ sender: UIButton) {

   manager.startUpdatingLocation()
   }
   ```
3. For the two other UIViews just create a UILabel for the temperature and an UIImageView for the cloud icon. And for the background color of the UILabel and the UIImageView and its corner radius you can do something similar as the ones i did for the button but this time choosing the right corners for the UIImageView and the left corners for the UILabel.

Here is the output: Of course you can use better sized icon images for your buttons.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Subviews on top of the map view. The i is an iOS resource. UIButton -> type -> Detail Disclosure